# Trigger the second jquery calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two jquery calendars in my page( #from and #to). My question is how to popup the second calendar("#to"), after selecting the date in first calendar ("#from") popup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `.datepicker( "show" )` function in `onSelect` function

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
   onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
      $("#to").datepicker( "show" );
   }
});
```

Comment: Partially working, the second calendar ("#to"), popping up and disappeared immediately :(